# Is there any platform to build a classifieds website similar to Magento or WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, cms, wordpress, magento

I am looking for a platform similar to Magento or Wordpress where I can add different categories and specify filters for my website. It could be a simple classifieds website or a movie listing website or car listing website. Is there any platform which I can use to configure these values and launch product quickly?

Wordpress is good for only creating blog websites. But I am looking for a single platform which can help me build 3 different types of websites - lets say:

- https://www.cars.com/
- https://www.zillow.com/
- or may be a pornhub.com

All 3 of these sites share a single thing:

- They have different categories and list of items for display(listing page) and a detail product page.

Is there any platform to help me build all 3 of them ?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly any CMS or platform supporting searching (which is trivial for a programmer to build himself) would be a candidate. Maybe specify why Wordpress **doesn't** suit your needs and what are the additional requirements.

Comment: @Thomas, Wordpress is good for only creating blog websites.
 I am looking to for a single platform which can help me build 3 different types of websites lets say: 
https://www.cars.com/ 
https://www.zillow.com/
or may be a pornhub.com
All 3 of these sites share a single thing :
- They have different categories and list of items for display(listing page) and a detail product page.
Is there any platform to help me build all 3 of them ?

Comment: All 3 could have been built using WordPress :)

Comment: Yes, But we'll need to customize accordingly. 
We can create an ecommerce website too using Wordpress.
But it will need so many edits and customizations.
Instead we have a tool called Magento to ease out creating an ecommerce website.
Do we have a similar platform to create a classifieds website

Comment: Hi @Thomas, What do you think ....?